# openfire service stop automatically in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: openfire

My XMPP service stopped automatically. it happens every 2 or 3 days. I have to restart service manually what could be the issue? it really a big issue and my application is live.

Error log:

> at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
>       2016.01.31 06:30:47 org.jivesoftware.openfire.plugin.rest.exceptions.RESTExceptionMapper -
>   UserNotFoundException: Could not get user with ressource 173 
>       2016.01.31 06:35:26 org.jivesoftware.openfire.plugin.rest.exceptions.RESTExceptionMapper -
>   UserNotFoundException: Could not get user with ressource 162

Comment: You should be more precise by providing logs. Have you done any custom configurations on openfire?

Comment: not at all see my updated question

Comment: I think there is an error when connecting to database, check database and driver